# How to remove the single quotation mark from a list in Python

Tags: python, string, list, integer, quotations

I am trying to remove the single quotation marks from this list:

```
list = ['amazed, 10']
```

and convert it to

```
list = ['amazed', 10]
```

I used `list= [x.strip('') for x in list]` but it does not work.

Is there a workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not "removing quotation marks", you're converting a string into a string and a number. You can't remove quotation marks from this string because it doesn't contain any.

Comment: don't use `list` as a variable name it shadows the `list` type

Answer (score 3):

You need to `split` but not `strip`, as your list contains a single string `'amazed, 10'` that expected to be split into 2 items - `'amazed'` and `10`:

```
lst = ['amazed, 10']
lst = [int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in lst[0].split(', ')]
print(lst)
```

The output:

```
['amazed', 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
>>> l = ['amazed, 10']
>>> l = l[0].split(", ")
>>> l
['amazed', ' 10']
```

Answer (score 0):

as it is a single item in the list, u can split the string using split() method.

```
list=list[0].split(', ')
```

it will give two separate strings.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to split your list to two elements. Next, strip white space and than convert the second element (a string of number) to number (Iv'e converted it to integer but you can convert to float or whatever).

```
ll = ['amazed, 10']
ll = ll[0].split(",")
ll[1] = int(ll[1].strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
lst = ['amazed, 10']

lst = [int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in lst[0].replace(',', '').split()]
```